# How to view nodes that only you have published?

Tags: 7, users

I need to be able to incorporate into my system a method for which users can view nodes that only they have created.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to implement [`hook_node_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) in a custom module.  Something like

```
function MYMODULE_node_access ($node, $op, $account) {
  if ($op == 'view' && $node->uid != $account->uid) {
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  }
  else {
    return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
  }
}
```

should be a start.

Comment: As side note, `hook_node_access()` is not invoked for node listings, such as RSS feeds, or the default front page (/node).

Comment: I used this method.  I also used it to implement my tagging mechanism (allowing users to edit content they've been tagged in).  Pretty sweet.  <3 Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the [content_access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) module to be pretty helpful for this kind of thing.

Just enable this on the content type you want to control, and make sure that "view any content" is unchecked for authenticated users, and that "view own content" is checked for authenticated users.